# SQL management studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Can you open a sql express 2014 database in sql management studio 2008?

Comment: here is the link for your reference http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please edit your question to a meaningful title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can open a SQL Express 2014 database in SQL Management Studio 2008, although not everything in the Object Explorer will work. For example when you try to use the table designer an error will be thrown, however, it will have no problem running SQL queries against the database.